# Counting with booleans

Tags: java, boolean

I was wondering if I could add booleans up like numbers. I am making something that uses a grid, and I want it to find the surrounding squares and return a number.
EDIT:
This is how I count with booleans.

```
 int count = 0;
 for (int x = -1; x<=1;x++){
   for (int y = -1; y <=1;y++){
     if (grid[xPos+x][yPos+y]){
        count++;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: How do you count with booleans? Provide an example, please

Comment: This isn't Conway's Game of Life by the way, is it?

Comment: Don't forget to not count the center position, when x == 0 and y == 0, unless you're sure you want to do that. Also, do you need to check for edge conditions where x < 0 or y < 0, or x > max X or y > max Y?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
boolean[] bools = ...
int sum = 0;
for(boolean b : bools) {
    sum += b ? 1 : 0;
}
```

This assumes that you want `true` to be `1` and `false` to be `0`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It is, but I'm modifying it so people can adjust the rules.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Jeffrey's answer, don't forget:

- If your at the center cell of your nested for loops, don't check the grid, and don't add to count. Else you're counting the cell itself in its neighbor count. In your situation, it's were `(x == 0 && y == 0)`
- You will need to check if the cell is on the edge, and if so make sure you're not trying to count cells that are off the grid. I've done this using something like this: `int xMin = Math.max(cellX - 1, 0);` where xMin is the lower bound of one of the for loops. I do similar for y, and similar for the maximum side of the grid. In your code this will happen when `xPos + x < 0` or `xPos + x >= MAX_X` (MAX_X is a constant for the max x value allowed for the grid), and similar for the y side of things.

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal? Speed? Readability? Code terseness?

If you're seeking speed, think about minimizing the number of memory accesses. If you can force your booleans to be stored as bits, you could use >> and & to compare only the bits you care about in each row. Maybe something like this:

```
 byte grid[m][n / 8];

 int neighbor_count = 0;
 for (int row = yPos - 1; row < yPos + 1; row++) {
   // calculate how much to shift the bits over.
   int shift = 5 - (xPos - 1 % 8);
   if (shift > 0) {
     // exercise for the reader - span bytes.
   } else {
     // map value of on-bits to count of on bits
     static byte count[8] = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3];
     // ensure that only the lowest 3 bits are on.
     low3 = (grid[row][xPos / 8] >> shift) & 7;
     // look up value in map
     neighbor_count += count[low3];
   }
```

*caveat coder*: this is untested and meant for illustration only. It also contains no bounds-checking: a way around that is to iterate from 1 to max - 2 and have a border of unset cells. Also you should subtract 1 if the cell being evaluated is on.

This might end up being slower than what you have. You can further optimize it by storing the bitmap in int32s (or whatever's native). You could also use multithreading, or just implement [Hashlife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashlife) :)

Obviously this optimizes away from terseness *and* readability. I think you've got maximum readability in your code.

As Jeffrey alludes to, storing a sparse array of 'on' booleans might be preferable to an array of values, depending on what you're doing.